# Put variable in getelementsbyclassname.innertext but not work?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this text

" This is Sam.

Sam is my friend.

Sam is ten years old.

Sam likes football."

You can see Sam is repeated so many times. I want to assign it to a variable so that when I need to I can change the character name. Here is how I write it

```js
var name = "sam"
document.getElementsByClassName("name").innerText= name;
```

```html
<p> This is <span class="name"></span>.</p>
<p> <span class="name"></span> is my friend</p>
<p> <span class="name"></span> is ten years old.</p>
<p> <span class="name"></span> likes football.</p>
```

However, it didn't work.
I also use **document.querySelectorAll("span.name").innerText= name;** but still didn't work.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` (array like) - so you have to iterate on it

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Try setting the `innerText` for the first array value.

Comment: @AbrarHossain - Not an array, an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I have put more details in my question. Can you check and help me? Thank you

Comment: @TheFox - See the answers in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return). You need a loop.